# How to register Notification Center in class iOS

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I am new to ios programming, I wanted to register notification center in the class, not in the view controller, I want to send some action from one view controller this custom class receives that action and it performs some view controller navigation.I wanted to have custom notification center in ios.

code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "key"), object: nil)
class MainReceiver: NotificationCenter
{
    override func post(name aName: NSNotification.Name, object anObject: Any?)
    {
        print("coming here")
    }

}
```

Comment: you can use uiviewcontroller's extension .

Answer (score 0):

Here you have snipped code:

```
class MainReceiver {

    init() {

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleMethod(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notification_Name"), object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func handleMethod(_ notification: Notification) {
        // handle
    }
}
```

Comment: should i initialize this class, i don't want to initialize any class i wanted to pass some action that class receives that action based on that it performs whatever i want

Comment: @darkknight That's what `init` is short for.

Comment: i don't want to initilize any class,i want to extend notification center if any one send some action through notification post,it will receive that action i want to perform some navigation based on that action

Comment: The way the notification center works is that it waits for someone to post a notification, then looks up all the objects that asked be notified of that notification and calls the registered action (selector) on them (optionally with the notification as an argument). This action can do whatever you want — if you want, make it do the navigation — and it can exist on whatever object you want.

Comment: i want like broadcast receiver,i want to receive it in throught the application without registering everywhere,thats why i extended notification center

Comment: so you are saying that i need to initialise one class that should add some observer,but how can i present view controller from custom class

Answer (score 0):

From [Apple's NSNotificationCenter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter):

> Each running Cocoa program has a default notification center. You typically don’t create your own.

I'm not sure why you think you want to create your own notification center, but trust me, you don't.

---

However, you can easily subscribe an object (an instance of a custom class, like you say you want to use) to notifications:

```
// let object = Whatever()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(object, selector: #selector(didReceive(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "key"), object: nil)
// object's didReceive(notification:) function will now be called when a notification with the specified name is posted. This can be posted from anywhere.
```

A while back, the function had to be decorated with the `@objc` attribute. I'm not sure if that's still the case, but if so, you'd use `@objc func didReceive(notification: Notification)` as your declaration in the receiving class.

Comment: i don't want to initialize any class,i just want to pass some action,particular class receives that action it performs whatever i want

Comment: @darkknight If you're trying to say that you want to use a class method, that's a bit of an anti-pattern. You should have an object listening. Such an instance is reasonably cheap in memory these days.

Comment: like android broadcast receiver,we declare in manifest file,it receives action from throught the application

Comment: This isn't Android, and you're going to have to change the way you look at things a little bit. See my comment on the other answer for some more explanation on `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: so you are saying that i need to initialise one class that should add some observer,but how can i present view controller from custom class

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I think what you are looking for is the blocked based variant for the NotificationCenter.

You can find it in the official [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver).

Example code from the docs:

```
let center = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
self.localeChangeObserver = center.addObserverForName(NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: mainQueue) { (note) in
print("The user's locale changed to: \(NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier)")
```

Comment: how can i extend notification center to class

Comment: Do you mean to create a new class which inherits the NotificationCenter? I don't understand completely what do you want to say by "extend notification center to class". A detailed question would be helpful.

Comment: i want to extend notification center class,wherever i receive some action i will perform in that class

Comment: You can achieve that by creating a new class, it doesn't need to extend NotificationCenter, only to use it. And you have two possibilities to use it, the one I mentioned or the one mentioned in the other comments.